# Minimum value problem without derivative

Tags: functions, triangles, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, slope

Each straight line with negative slope which passes through the point (3; 7) in the rectangular coordinate system
Oxy, together with the x and y coordinate axes encloses right triangle. Find the smallest one among the areas of
such triangles. without derivative.

Comment: But what did you try?

Comment: I figured out area of triangle, but i couldn't find minimum value. now i understand it using AM-GM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(-m)$ is a slop of the line. Hence, $m>0$.

Thus, $y-7=-m(x-3)$ is an equation of the line, which intersects the $x$-axis in the point $A$ and the $y$- axis in the point $B$.

Hence, $B(0,7+3m)$ and $A\left(\frac{3m+7}{m},0\right)$.

The area of $\Delta OAB$ it's $$\frac{(3m+7)^2}{2m}.$$
Now, by AM-GM
$$\frac{(3m+7)^2}{2m}=\frac{1}{2}\left(9m+\frac{49}{m}+42\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}\left(2\sqrt{9m\cdot\frac{49}{m}}+42\right)=42.$$
The equality occurs for $9m=\frac{49}{m}$, which says that the answer is $42$.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain AM-GM part?

Comment: @AKZG Yes, of course! AM-GM here it's the following. For positives $a$ and $b$ we have $\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$. Proof: we need to prove $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$ or $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\geq0,$ which is obvious. In our case $a=9m$ and $b=\frac{49}{m}$. Thus, by AM-GM $9m+\frac{49}{m}\geq2\sqrt{9m\cdot\frac{49}{m}}=42$.

Comment: why a=9m and b=49/m?

Comment: @AKZG I just use AM-GM for this numbers. Just substitute $a=9m$ and $b=\frac{49}{m}$ to $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the line has the equation
$$y=mx+n$$ The given Point is situated on this line, then we have
$$7=3m+n$$ or $$y=mx-3m+7$$ the intersection Points with the axis are
$$P_1(0;7-3m)$$
$$P_2\left(\frac{3m-7}{m};0\right)$$
can you go further?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=ax+b$ cuts $x$-axis and $y$-axis at $(x_0,0)$ and $(0,y_0)$, respectively.

Then:
$$\begin{cases} 0=ax_0+b \\ y_0=a\cdot 0+b \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} a=-\frac{y_0}{x_0} \\ b=y_0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow y=-\frac{y_0}{x_0}x+y_0.$$

The line passes through $(3,7)$:
$$7=-\frac{y_0}{x_0}\cdot 3+y_0 \Rightarrow x_0y_0=7x_0+3y_0\ge 2\sqrt{21x_0y_0} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x_0y_0}\ge 2\sqrt{21} \Rightarrow x_0y_0\ge 84 \Rightarrow \frac{x_0y_0}{2}\ge 42.$$

And equality occurs when $x_0=6, y_0=14$.